# How to take content from json using regular expression (regex) in php

Tags: php, javascript, regex, json

I need to extract json which is existing inside some html tags. how to extract name(key) values from below json using regular expression

```
<div id="gwt_products_display_results" class="gwt_products_display_results">
                <span class="JSON" style="display: none;">
{
    "products": [
        {
            "targetURL": "/athena-mineral-fabric-by-the-yard/262682",
            "listIndex": "0",
            "minimumPrice": 20,
            "categoryOnSale": "false",
            "mfPartNumber": "FF010ATM",
            "hasAtLeastOneBuyableAndPublishedItem": "true",
            "attributes": [],
            "partNumber": "b_FF010ATM",
            "itemAsProduct": "true",
            "iapAttribute": "",
            "productDetailTargetURL": "/athena-mineral-fabric-by-the-yard/262682",
            "iapAttributeCode": "",
            "beanType": "bundle",
            "name": "Athena Mineral Fabric by the Yard",
            "maxListPrice": 0,
            "thumbNail": "null",
            "hasSaleSKUs": false,
            "productId": "262682",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "hasMoreColors": false,
            "xPriceLabel": "null",
            "minListPrice": 0,
            "maximumPrice": 20,
            "iapAttributeDisplayName": "",
            "shortDescription": "null",
            "listId": "SEARCHRESULTS",
            "categoryId": "null"
        },
        {
            "targetURL": "/athena-slate-fabric-by-the-yard/262683",
            "listIndex": "1",
            "minimumPrice": 20,
            "categoryOnSale": "false",
            "mfPartNumber": "FF010ATS",
            "hasAtLeastOneBuyableAndPublishedItem": "true",
            "attributes": [],
            "partNumber": "b_FF010ATS",
            "itemAsProduct": "true",
            "iapAttribute": "",
            "productDetailTargetURL": "/athena-slate-fabric-by-the-yard/262683",
            "iapAttributeCode": "",
            "beanType": "bundle",
            "name": "Athena Slate Fabric by the Yard",
            "maxListPrice": 0,
            "thumbNail": "null",
            "hasSaleSKUs": false,
            "productId": "262683",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "hasMoreColors": false,
            "xPriceLabel": "null",
            "minListPrice": 0,
            "maximumPrice": 20,
            "iapAttributeDisplayName": "",
            "shortDescription": "null",
            "listId": "SEARCHRESULTS",
            "categoryId": "null"
        },
        {
            "targetURL": "/typewriter-keys-giclee/261307",
            "listIndex": "2",
            "minimumPrice": 259,
            "categoryOnSale": "false",
            "mfPartNumber": "WD813",
            "hasAtLeastOneBuyableAndPublishedItem": "true",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "S7 - Overlay 1": "blank"
                }
            ],
            "partNumber": "p_WD813",
            "itemAsProduct": "true",
            "iapAttribute": "",
            "productDetailTargetURL": "/typewriter-keys-giclee/261307",
            "iapAttributeCode": "",
            "beanType": "product",
            "name": "Typewriter Keys Giclee",
            "maxListPrice": 0,
            "thumbNail": "null",
            "hasSaleSKUs": false,
            "productId": "261307",
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "hasMoreColors": false,
            "xPriceLabel": "null",
            "minListPrice": 0,
            "maximumPrice": 259,
            "iapAttributeDisplayName": "",
            "shortDescription": "null",
            "listId": "SEARCHRESULTS",
            "categoryId": "null"
        }
    ]
}
</span>
</div>
```

what I have tried so far is

```
<span class="JSON" style="display: none;">([\s\S]+?)<\/span>
```

Comment: Why??? Just use `json_decode`.

Comment: Why for everything-in-the-world-that-might-be-considered-holy’s sake would you want to use regular expressions on a data structure like JSON? __Parse__ it into an object/array, and access the values you want directly or by looping over it.

Comment: If you are planning to drop `json_encode()` and write your own full-fledge JSON parser you'll probably need much more than regular expressions because JSON allows indefinite nesting level of arbitrary elements. Are you looking for something to do this Summer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, regular expression? As the other people here mentioned, you can use json_decode to parse it to an array and process it.

But if you insist on regular expression I would say `/"(.+?)":/` will match ALL keys if your JSON have exact format as shown.

**UPDATE**

So you are getting it from a html string. Consider the variable is $html and as you insist on regular expression, parse the json using regex as follows and then decode. To parse the keys, use `array_keys()`

```
preg_match('/<span.*?class="JSON".*?>(.+?)<\/span>/s', $html, $matches);

$decoded_array = json_decode($matches[1], true);

print_r($decoded_array);

$keys = array_keys($decoded_array['products'][0]);

print_r($keys);
```

Comment: Acctually i am talking data  from html structure so its difficult to use json_decode

Comment: Then parse the json from html and then decode. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert it to an array and then get the names using `array_keys();`

```
$array = json_decode($json);

$keys = array_keys($array['products']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to find the `span` elements which contain the JSON, and then [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) that. Here's a rough example to get you on your way: -

```
<?php
$html = '
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gwt_products_display_results" class="gwt_products_display_results">
            <span class="JSON" style="display: none;">
            {
                "products": [
                    {
                        "targetURL": "/athena-mineral-fabric-by-the-yard/262682",
                        "listIndex": "0",
                        "minimumPrice": 20,
                        "categoryOnSale": "false",
                        "mfPartNumber": "FF010ATM",
                        "hasAtLeastOneBuyableAndPublishedItem": "true",
                        "attributes": [],
                        "partNumber": "b_FF010ATM",
                        "itemAsProduct": "true",
                        "iapAttribute": "",
                        "productDetailTargetURL": "/athena-mineral-fabric-by-the-yard/262682",
                        "iapAttributeCode": "",
                        "beanType": "bundle",
                        "name": "Athena Mineral Fabric by the Yard",
                        "maxListPrice": 0,
                        "thumbNail": "null",
                        "hasSaleSKUs": false,
                        "productId": "262682",
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "hasMoreColors": false,
                        "xPriceLabel": "null",
                        "minListPrice": 0,
                        "maximumPrice": 20,
                        "iapAttributeDisplayName": "",
                        "shortDescription": "null",
                        "listId": "SEARCHRESULTS",
                        "categoryId": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "targetURL": "/athena-slate-fabric-by-the-yard/262683",
                        "listIndex": "1",
                        "minimumPrice": 20,
                        "categoryOnSale": "false",
                        "mfPartNumber": "FF010ATS",
                        "hasAtLeastOneBuyableAndPublishedItem": "true",
                        "attributes": [],
                        "partNumber": "b_FF010ATS",
                        "itemAsProduct": "true",
                        "iapAttribute": "",
                        "productDetailTargetURL": "/athena-slate-fabric-by-the-yard/262683",
                        "iapAttributeCode": "",
                        "beanType": "bundle",
                        "name": "Athena Slate Fabric by the Yard",
                        "maxListPrice": 0,
                        "thumbNail": "null",
                        "hasSaleSKUs": false,
                        "productId": "262683",
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "hasMoreColors": false,
                        "xPriceLabel": "null",
                        "minListPrice": 0,
                        "maximumPrice": 20,
                        "iapAttributeDisplayName": "",
                        "shortDescription": "null",
                        "listId": "SEARCHRESULTS",
                        "categoryId": "null"
                    }
                ]
            }
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
';

$document   = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xpath      = new DOMXPath($document);
$spans      = $xpath->query('//div/span[@class="JSON"]');

foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $catalog = json_decode($span->nodeValue);
    printf("We found %d products.\n", count($catalog->products));
    foreach ($catalog->products as $index => $product) {
        printf("Product #%d - %s.\n", ++$index, $product->name);
    }
}

/*
    We found 2 products.
    Product #1 - Athena Mineral Fabric by the Yard.
    Product #2 - Athena Slate Fabric by the Yard.
*/
```

Comment: sorry to say i need regex instead of DOMXpath